# PHP - exec sudo command returns nothing

Tags: php, ubuntu, exec

There are many questions on this topic, but my situation is quite strange.

I am trying to print out `exec("sudo -u root whoami")` in php. But it returns nothing.

I added `%www-data ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL` via `sudo visudo` but no luck on what is happenning, no error, just not printing out anything.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm going to put it out there that this is a terrible idea. Your webserver / PHP should not have root access to your entire system.

Comment: Apart from the horrible security gap you are about to create: your sudoers entry does _not_ mean that no password is required to actually execute the command under the changed user id. A password you cannot provide in an interactive manner. You want to read about the `NOPASSWD` option the sudoers file offers, you want to read about that in the documentation. But once more: this is a bad idea for security reasons.

Comment: Also, just tested using the PHP CLI under an existing super user and `echo exec("sudo -u root whoami")` works fine give or take requiring password.

Comment: Change it to `exec("sudo -u root whoami 2>&1")` so that you'll see error messages.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is your webserver going to enter the password for `sudo`?

Your configuration allows the webserver-user to run all commands on the server. But that requires the user to enter their password. And the webserver

1. can't do that interactively
2. doesn't even have a apassword

So **if** you want to do what you try to do (giving the process running PHP root-access to the machine is a **very bad idea**) you should add this to your sudo-config:

```
%www-data     ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/whoami
```

That allows the group www-data to run `whoami` as root **without** an interctive password-prompt

Comment: I added `%www-data ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`  and I thought that includes what you mentioned? I know it's a bad idea to do this but it did not work

Comment: Actually what you suggests works perfectly fine. But is there a safer way to do it or am i going against all the security rules?

Comment: And although it does not require password, it does not actually create anything. I tried with a simple mkdir command and no folder created. Thanks in advance

Comment: It only allows you to run whoami. if you want to run mkdir you will need to add that behind the whoami. Have a look at the sudo documentation

Comment: Suggested answer from be below that keeps sudo and web priv seperate